# Use regex to find a phrase with symbols in an URL

Tags: regex

I have several pages with the current url:

```
onclick="location.href='https://www.mydomain.com/shop/bags
```

at the end of each url there's something like this:

```
?cid=Black'"
or 
?cid=Beige'"
or 
?cid=Green'"
```

What I need is a regex to find `?cid=` in each url and then replace everything from `?cid=` to the ending `'`

CUrrently I have this:
    `.?cid=.*?'`

This finds occurences of `?cid=` in EVERY line of code. I only want it to find occurrences in `onclick="location.href='https://www.mydomain.com/shop/bags`

Any one got any solutions for this?

**UPDATE** 
Sorry for the initial confusion. I'm using this program http://www.araxis.com/replace-in-files/index-eur.html which allows the use of regex's to find elements. I think it says it allows PERL style regex.

Thanks

Comment: What language are you using? It might make more sense to parse the URL into its component parts than use a regular expression.

Comment: I'm actually using this program [link](http://www.araxis.com/replace-in-files/index-eur.html) which allows the use of regex to find specific elements. Sorry I should have explained it

Comment: Further to Ben's comments, different regex engines have different capabilities and syntax. We need to know what you are using before we can answer.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I forgot to explain, the program allows the use of PERL style regex I think

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) syntax to match `?cid=something` preceded by the URL and followed by a `'`

This pattern should work:

```
(?<=\Qhttps://www.mydomain.com/shop/bags\E)\?cid=[^']++(?=')
```

If you replace that pattern with your replacement then the entire bit from `?cid` until `'` will be replaced.

Here is an example in Java (ignore the slightly different syntax):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String[] in = {
        "onclick=\"location.href='https://www.mydomain.com/shop/bags?cid=Black'",
        "onclick=\"location.href='https://www.mydomain.com/shop/bags?cid=Beige'",
        "onclick=\"location.href='https://www.mydomain.com/shop/bags?cid=Green'"
    };
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\Qhttps://www.mydomain.com/shop/bags\\E)\\?cid=[^']++(?=')");
    for(final String string : in) {
        final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(string);
        final String replaced = m.replaceAll("SOMETHING_ELSE");
        System.out.println(replaced);
    }
}
```

Output

```
onclick="location.href='https://www.mydomain.com/shop/bagsSOMETHING_ELSE'
onclick="location.href='https://www.mydomain.com/shop/bagsSOMETHING_ELSE'
onclick="location.href='https://www.mydomain.com/shop/bagsSOMETHING_ELSE'
```

This assumes, obviously, that your tools supports lookaround.

This should certainly work if you just use Perl directly rather than via your magic tool

```
perl -pi -e '/s/(?<=\Qhttps://www.mydomain.com/shop/bags\E)\?cid=[^\']++(?=\')/SOMETHING_ELSE/g' *some_?glob*.pattern
```

**EDIT**

Another idea is to use a capturing group and a backreference, replace

```
(\Qhttps://www.mydomain.com/shop/bags\E)\?cid=[^']++
```

With

```
$1SOMETHING_ELSE
```

Another test case in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String[] in = {
        "onclick=\"location.href='https://www.mydomain.com/shop/bags?cid=Black'",
        "onclick=\"location.href='https://www.mydomain.com/shop/bags?cid=Beige'",
        "onclick=\"location.href='https://www.mydomain.com/shop/bags?cid=Green'"
    };
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\Qhttps://www.mydomain.com/shop/bags\\E)\\?cid=[^']++");
    for(final String string : in) {
        final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(string);
        final String replaced = m.replaceAll("$1SOMETHING_ELSE");
        System.out.println(replaced);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
onclick="location.href='https://www.mydomain.com/shop/bagsSOMETHING_ELSE'
onclick="location.href='https://www.mydomain.com/shop/bagsSOMETHING_ELSE'
onclick="location.href='https://www.mydomain.com/shop/bagsSOMETHING_ELSE'
```

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately I don't think the program supports this, any other solution? Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @Armali in which regex engine? Do you have a documentation link?

Comment: Perhaps user2028856's regex engine doesn't like the extra '+' in your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Find

```
(onclick="location.href='https://www.mydomain.com/shop/bags.*?)\?cid=.*?'
```

Replace

```
$1something'
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this pattern

```
\?cid=[^']*
```

The idea is to use a character class that exclude the final simple quote, then you avoid to use a lazy quantifier.

Note: you can use a possessive quantifier if supported to give the regex engine less work:

```
\?cid=[^']*+
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, could you please offer a small explanation on how the above regex works? Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP want. The task to is replace the query string on for the specified URL.

Comment: @Casimir umm this doesn't really work, it doesn't find complete words in the `?cid=`. I get things like `?cid=Bla` when it's supposed to be `?cid=Black`